# ERROR 1064 (42000) MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '. SET = hello world WHERE . =3' at line 1

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i try to edit wordpress mysql database with :

```
root@vps:~# echo "UPDATE `wp_options` SET  `option_value` =  'hello world' WHERE `option_id` =3" | mysql -u root -D dbname;
-bash: wp_options: command not found
-bash: option_value: command not found
-bash: option_id: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET   =  'hello world' WHERE  =3' at line 1
```

mysql --version

```
root@vps:~# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.28-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first shell command, as you can see from the errors reported by `bash`:

```
echo "UPDATE `wp_options` SET  `option_value` =  'hello world' WHERE `option_id` =3"
```

Before running a command, the shell (`bash`) performs several substitutions on the command line. One of them is the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (the only type of substitution that is present in the command above). This substitution identifies the substrings surrounded by backticks (`` ` ``), runs them as separate commands and replaces them with their output.

In your case, `bash` finds `wp_options`, `option_value` and `option_id` surrounded by `` ` ``, tries to run them as commands and fails because they are not Linux commands. Then it replaces them with the output generated by running these commands (there is no output because they didn't run) and the command becomes:

```
echo "UPDATE  SET   =  'hello world' WHERE  =3" | mysql
```

Of course, this is not a valid query and `mysql` complains too.

The simple solution to this issue is to wrap the query into single quotes (`'`); `bash` does not perform [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) on the arguments wrapped in single quotes. In this case you need to use double quotes around the values of strings inside the query.

The command should be:

```
echo 'UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = "hello world" WHERE `option_id` = 3' | mysql -u root -D dbname
```

Another option is to not wrap the table and field names in backticks in the query. They are not MySQL keywords and they do not contain special characters, there is no need to put them in backticks. In this case you can let the query in double quotes as it doesn't contain now anything special:

```
echo "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'hello world' WHERE option_id = 3" | mysql -u root -D dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

After try some trial and error then i get the answer

```
root@vps:~# echo "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value =  'hello world' WHERE option_id =3" | mysql -u root -D dbname;
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE expects you to name a table, no a field of a table, so it would be `dbname.wp_options` instead of `dbname.wp_options.option_id`

```
echo UPDATE `dbname`.`wp_options` SET  `option_value` =  'hello world' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_id` =3 | mysql -u root
```

I personally prefer to use `UPDATE wp_options` and tell the mysql client which database to connect to with `mysql -D dbname`.